# independent times to ensure minimum cut of graph at least one trial succeeds

Tags: algorithm, minimum-cut

I just finished with the first module in the algo specialization course in coursera.

There was an exam question that i could not quite understand. I have passed that exam, so there's no point for me to retake it.

Out of curiosity, I want to learn the principles around this question.

The question was posted as such:

> Suppose that a randomized algorithm succeeds (e.g., correctly computes
>   the minimum cut of a graph) with probability p (with 0 < p < 1). Let ϵ
>   be a small positive number (less than 1).
>
> How many independent times do you need to run the algorithm to ensure
>   that, with probability at least 1−ϵ, at least one trial succeeds?

The options given were:

> log(1−p)/logϵ
>
> log(p)/logϵ
>
> logϵ/log(p)
>
> logϵ/log(1−p)

I made two attempts and both were wrong. My attempts were:

> 1. log(1−p)/logϵ
> 2. logϵ/log(1−p)

It's not so much I want to know the right answer. I want to learn the principles behind this question and what it's asking for. So that I know how to answer similar questions in future.

I have posted this on the forum, but nobody answered after a month. So I am trying it out here.

NO need to post the answer directly. If you got me to get to aha moment, i will mark it as correct.

Thanks.

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, the fact that the algorithm computes a min-cut seems irrelevant - an effectively identical question could read "You have a bag of coins that have `p` probability of landing heads when flipped (with `0 < p < 1`). Let ϵ be a small positive number (less than 1). How many coins do you need to simultaneously flip such that, with probability `1- ϵ`, at least one coin lands on heads?"
Not that this implies an answer, but cutting away extraneous info is always good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How many independent times do you need to run the algorithm to ensure that, with probability at least 1−ϵ, at least one trial succeeds?

Let's rephrase it a bit:

> What is the smallest number of independent trials such that the probability of all of them failing is less than or equal to ϵ?

By the definition of [independent events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#More_than_two_events), the probability of all of them occurring is the product of their individual probabilities. Since the probability of one trial failing is `(1-p)`, the probability of `n` trials failing is `(1-p)^n`.

This gives us an inequality for `n`:

```
(1-p)^n <= ϵ
```

Comment: i understand your phrasing. which is helpful. but using what you gave me means the answer is `logϵ/log(1−p)`. However, I know for a fact that answer is wrong. Which means, either a) the reasoning you gave is not correct (seems unlikely) or b) I reasoned to the wrong answer despite your explanation or c) your reasoning is right. the implied answer is right. the marking system had an error

Am I right to say that your reasoning implies `logϵ/log(1−p)`?

Comment: @KimStacks Yes, it's `logϵ/log(1−p)`. I think we can eliminate other answers on common sense grounds. 1) `ϵ`, `p` and `1-p` are all less than `1`, so their logarithms are negative and the logarithms' absolute values increase as the the corresponding numbers decrease.

Comment: @KimStacks 2) The more likely the algorithm is to succeed, the fewer times we need to run it. So as `p` increases, `n` must decrease. This eliminates `log(1−p)/logϵ` and `logϵ/log(p)`. 3) The more confident we need to be that that the algorithm succeeds at least once, the more times we need to run it. So as `ϵ` decreases, `n` must increase. This eliminates `log(1−p)/logϵ` and `log(p)/logϵ`.

Comment: Thanks, took me a while to follow your logic of elimination worth it!